# Checking if a multi string is found in one of multiple columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql

i need to find multi string in multi columns in mysql.

```
select * from myTable WHERE name LIKE '%stack%';
```

This obviously works. However, what I need to do is that if both name and surname are checked multi string would do something like this:

```
select * from myTable WHERE (name or surname) LIKE '%stack%','%over%','%flow%';
```

if similar above code that work does not exist. please tell me how can checking multi string in a column in mySQL with like statement:

```
select * from myTable WHERE name LIKE '%stack%','%over%','%flow%';
```

Comment: Why not checkout full text search in mysql, that perhaps you needed. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep it simple and do:

```
select * from myTable WHERE name LIKE '%stack%' OR 
                            name LIKE '%over%' OR
                            name LIKE '%flow%';
```

or:

```
select * from myTable WHERE name LIKE '%stack%' AND
                            name LIKE '%over%' AND
                            name LIKE '%flow%';
```

This doesn't look as nice as the REGEXP from Young, but it doesn't have the unexpected behaviour REGEXP can have given that user input can be anything. With REGEXP you really need to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select * from myTable WHERE name REGEXP 'stack|over|flow';
```

Though it's not a `like` solution.